# AnkhSVN: How to fix error - "You failed to authorize against the remote repository."?

Tags: ankhsvn

I've been using VS2010 and I want to use some type of source control.  I installed Subversion and AnkhSVN.  I was able to commit my solution to the SVN and I'm able to retrieve it.

Now I would like to password protect the repository.  I edited the configuration files and everything appears to be protected the way I would like.  I've tested the password configuration and read/write using TortoiseSVN so I know its not in the Subversion settings.

My problem is I cannot get AnkhSVN to commit to the repository now.  It appears to not recognize the SVN requites a username and password and it throws the error message "You failed to authorize against the remote repository."

How would I go about setting up AnkhSVN to accept a username and password so I can use this SVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using your name in Upper case.  Your user name is case sensitive.

Comment: My login name on this computer is "Neil" and the username for SVN I selected as "neil".  The username and password dialog that pops up when you first install AnkhSVN auto filled with "Neil" and I didn't even give it a second thought.  Uninstalling/reinstalling prompted for the login information again and I used the correct case login name.  Thanks!